# Sink never used in Integration test in Flink

Tags: testing, apache-flink

I have a pretty simple Flink job I'm trying to test : I get a POJO from Kafka, make a couple of udf (a filter, a map and then a passage to SQL to enrich data with external BDD) and write the resulting Datastream in an Elastic Sink.

Following the [link in the docs](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-master/docs/dev/datastream/testing), I tried to follow the following steps to test the job.

Here is my code:

```
@ClassRule
public static MiniClusterWithClientResource testCluster =
        new MiniClusterWithClientResource(
                new MiniClusterResourceConfiguration.Builder()
                        .setNumberTaskManagers(1)
                        .setNumberSlotsPerTaskManager(2)
                        .build()
        );


@Test
public void testVodViewsPipeline() throws Exception {
    StreamExecutionEnvironment env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    env.setParallelism(2);
    CollectSink.values.clear();

    DataStream<myPOJO> testMessage = env.fromElements(testValue);

    DataStream<Row> endMessage = pipeline.VodViewsPipeline(env,testMessage);

    endMessage.addSink(new CollectSink());

    env.execute();


    assertTrue(CollectSink.values.contains("something"));
}



private static class CollectSink implements SinkFunction<Row> {

    public static final List<Row> values = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

    @Override
    public void invoke(Row value, SinkFunction.Context context) throws Exception {
        values.add(value);
    }
}
```

Through the debugger, it appears that the sink is never called. I'm not sure why but as a newbie, I'm probably making a big mistake I can't pinpoint. Any tips welcome.

Comment: From the code above, I think it would work. So I'd focus my attention on what's happening inside of `pipeline.VodViewsPipeline()`.